# Utilizing if statements with "&&" in Java, statement not printing despite criteria being fulfilled

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to make a basic "20 questions" type of thing to learn how to use if statements with boolean comparators like && in them. However, my "if" statements are not, uh, "doing" (sorry) even though their criteria are being satisfied (as far as I can tell).

When I compile, no matter what "answers" I input, the only output I get is "I'd ask you if I'm right..." ALA:

```
Think of an object, and I'll try to  guess it!
1. Is it an animal, vegetable, or mineral?vegetable
Is it bigger than a breadbox?yes
I'd ask you if I'm right, but I don't really care
```

I tried googling and searching but I feel like I'm missing out on something so basic that I'm just not seeing it. 
Here's the code:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String response1, response2;

    System.out.println("Think of an object, and I'll try to "
            + " guess it!");
    System.out.print("1. Is it an animal, vegetable, or mineral?");
    response1 = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print("Is it bigger than a breadbox?");
    response2 = keyboard.next();

    if(response1 == "animal" && response2 == "yes")
    {
        System.out.println("You're thinking of a moose");
    }
    if(response1 == "animal" && response2 == "no")
    {
        System.out.println("You're thinking of a squirrel");
    }
    if(response1 == "vegetable" && response2 == "yes")
    {
        System.out.println("You're thinking of a watermelon");
    }
    if(response1 == "vegetable" && response2 == "no")
    {
        System.out.println("You're thinking of a carrot");
    }
    if(response1 == "mineral" && response2 == "yes")
    {
        System.out.println("You're thinking of a Camaro");
    }
    if(response1 == "mineral" && response2 == "no")
    {
        System.out.println("You're thinking of a paper clip");
    }

    System.out.println("I'd ask you if I'm right, but I don't really care");
```

Thanks in advance to any respondents!

Comment: Cause of all string comarison problems.. [How do i compare the Strings???](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare strings like

```
if(response1.equals("animal")){

// do something 
}
```

`==` compares the exact values. So it compares if the primitive values are the same,

[String#.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) calls the comparison method of objects, which will compare the actual objects pointed by the `references`. In the case of `Strings`, it compares each character to see if they're `equal`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `equals()` to compare Strings not `==`.

Using your example:

```
if(response1.equals("animal") && response2.equals("yes"))
{
    System.out.println("You're thinking of a moose");
}...
```

Comment: Well, that did fix it, but why can't we use == for strings?

EDIT: Ah, I found the big answer thread answering this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is related to string comparisons and not with '&&' operator.
Use [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method for string comparison. '==' checks whether two references are pointing to the same memory object.

Replace your if check(s) for string comparison

from

```
if(response1 == "animal" && response2 == "yes")
```

to

```
if("animal".equals(response1) && "yes".equals(response2))
```

Here is a related post to understand more about string comparison in java

[Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 0):

Compare String values use `equalsIgnoreCase`

```
if(response1.equalsIgnoreCase("animal")){

 //process
}
```

conditional check for boolean values  [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/boolean_values.html)